# nodeclipse editbox plugin - unable to install

Tags: eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse, editbox

I have updated eclipse to 4.10 (2018-12/R), the cpp package
Running under ubuntu 18.04.
I tried to add nodeclipse editbox using the marketplace, but it cannot find the plugin.
Then tried the option help-install New Software, adding the repository provided in the github site (https://github.com/Nodeclipse/EditBox), as 
http://nodeclipse.github.io/dev.updates/editbox-1.0.0/

But I always get this error:
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.cpp, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://nodeclipse.github.io/dev.updates/editbox-1.0.0/plugins/pm.eclipse.editbox_1.0.0.201804021412.jar.
Connection reset

I have searched for the whole morning, and cannot find any reference to the possible cause of this error.
Any pointer will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like I solved it. Recording it here in case others come looking.
The problem was in the server that cut the file download midway.
So using the information in the error message, I was able to download and install directly the plugin. I did:
cd /opt/eclipse/plugins - To get the download directly into the plugin folder
Then used wget to download the folder directly:

wget http://nodeclipse.github.io/dev.updates/editbox-1.0.0/plugins/pm.eclipse.editbox_1.0.0.201804021412.jar

Restarted eclipse, and voila! It was working.
Simpler than I thougth.